# Proof by semantic argument

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have the following consequence:

${(r ∨ q ), (r \to (r \leftrightarrow q))} \vDash ((p∨q) ∧ (q∨p))$

My task is to prove it by Semantical Consequence:

So far, I assumed that there exsits a function $T:A->B$.
I know that $T((r ∨ q )) = 1$ and

$T((r→(r<->q)) = 1$, and I have to prove the validity of the latter.

I have applied the rules of T, for the first and second formulae and I arrived at something like:

$T(r) + T(q) = 1$  and $(/T(r) + T(q)) * (T(r) + /T(q) = 1$
From these two, I have to somehow prove that $T(q)$ is also 1, as this will satisfy what I had to prove at the begining, for any p of A.

I am stuck here. Can somebody give me a hint of what I have to do next?

I much appreciate your time!

Comment: By contradiction. Assume not, i.e. assume that there is a valuation $v$ such that the purported conclusion is False, that means: $v(p)=v(q)= \text F$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yessss! It worked! After 5 attempts, it worked! Thank you very much sir, for your time and patience! All the best!